# C# HtmlDecode Specific tags only

Tags: c#, asp.net, regex

I have a large htmlencoded string and i want decode only specific whitelisted html tags.

Is there a way to do this in c#, WebUtility.HtmlDecode() decodes everything.

`I am looking for an implementaiton of DecodeSpecificTags() that will pass below test.

```
    [Test]
    public void DecodeSpecificTags_SimpleInput_True()
    {
        string input = "&lt;span&gt;i am &lt;strong color=blue&gt;very&lt;/strong&gt; big &lt;br&gt;man.&lt;/span&gt;";
        string output = "&lt;span&gt;i am <strong color=blue>very</strong> big <br>man.&lt;/span&gt;";
        List<string> whiteList = new List<string>(){ "strong","br" } ;

        Assert.IsTrue(DecodeSpecificTags(whiteList,input) == output);
    }`
```

Comment: what are you trying to achieve? may be there is another and better way of doing so. also what you can do is take substring of the text you need to decode and then after decoding append it with remaining encoded text.

Answer (score 1):

A better approach could be to use some html parser like Agilitypack or csquery or Nsoup to find specific elements and decode it in a loop.

[check this for links and examples of parsers](http://www.geekonweb.com/86/jsoup-a-better-html-parser-than-htmlagilitypack#comment-431)

Check It, i did it using csquery :

```
string input = "&lt;span&gt;i am &lt;strong color=blue&gt;very&lt;/strong&gt; big &lt;br&gt;man.&lt;/span&gt;";
string output = "&lt;span&gt;i am <strong color=blue>very</strong> big <br>man.&lt;/span&gt;";

var decoded = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(output);
var encoded =input ; //  HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(decoded);

Console.WriteLine(encoded);
Console.WriteLine(decoded);

var doc=CsQuery.CQ.CreateDocument(decoded);

var paras=doc.Select("strong").Union(doc.Select ("br")) ;

var tags=new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>();
var counter=0;

foreach (var element in paras)
{
    HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(element.OuterHTML).Dump();
    var key ="---" + counter + "---";
    var value= HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(element.OuterHTML);
    var pair= new KeyValuePair<String,String>(key,value);

    element.OuterHTML = key ;
    tags.Add(pair);
    counter++;
}

var finalstring= HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(doc.Document.Body.InnerHTML);
finalstring.Dump();

foreach (var element in tags)
{
finalstring=finalstring.Replace(element.Key,element.Value);
}

Console.WriteLine(finalstring);
```

Comment: I may be missing some functionality of HtmlAgility, but i am not sure this will work, if the input is not html (because it has beeen encoded) ?

Comment: @PeteN - you could HtmlDecode the entire string, then visit each element and if it's not in your whitelist, re-encode it.

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this

```
public string DecodeSpecificTags(List<string> whiteListedTagNames,string encodedInput)
{
    String regex="";
    foreach(string s in whiteListedTagNames)
    {
        regex="&lt;"+@"\s*/?\s*"+s+".*?"+"&gt;";
        encodedInput=Regex.Replace(encodedInput,regex);
    }
    return encodedInput;
}
```

Comment: +1 for way how to solve the problem. @PeteN perfect, so you got the idea how you could solve it. You just have to adapt the regex to suit your specific usecase.

Comment: @winner_joiner yes +1 for solution, to be honest though i did get that far myself, it was the regex part i was struggling with :)

Comment: @Anirudh, sorry again, still fails to match, are u assuming whitespace after a tag?

Answer (score 0):

Or you could use HtmlAgility with a black list or white list based on your requirement. I'm using black listed approach.
My black listed tag is store in a text file, for example "script|img"

```
public static string DecodeSpecificTags(this string content, List<string> blackListedTags)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(content))
        {
            return content;
        }
        blackListedTags = blackListedTags.Select(t => t.ToLowerInvariant()).ToList();
        var decodedContent = HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(content);
        var document = new HtmlDocument();
        document.LoadHtml(decodedContent);
        decodedContent = blackListedTags.Select(blackListedTag => document.DocumentNode.Descendants(blackListedTag))
                .Aggregate(decodedContent,
                    (current1, nodes) =>
                        nodes.Select(htmlNode => htmlNode.WriteTo())
                            .Aggregate(current1,
                                (current, nodeContent) =>
                                    current.Replace(nodeContent, HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(nodeContent))));
        return decodedContent;
    }
```