# Decode specific HTML tag from Encoded line

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, decode, encode

I got this Encoded HTML-line:

```
&lt;b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt
```

This is saved in the database.

When I read this from the database, I need to Decode this.

But I only want to decode this tag: `&lt;br /&gt` (the line contains multiple times this tag).

I looked at this solution, but I didn't understand it well:

[C# HtmlDecode Specific tags only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17608077/c-sharp-htmldecode-specific-tags-only)

Can anyone give me some tips on how I can solve my problem?

Edit: I need to use `Server.HtmlDecode` to get breakline between sentences, so ''Replace''-string function won't work.

1. I'm saving encoded values to the database.
2. I'm reading the encoded values from the database.
3. I want to decode only the "&lr;br /&gt"-tag which will result in a breakline
4. The other tags should stay the same without decoding.

Comment: you can simply use [String.Replace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.replace(v=vs.110).aspx) for replace `&lt;br /&gt`

Comment: Why do you want to decode just one tag?  What are you ultimately going to do with the string?

Comment: @Tim I want to decode the <br /> tag so I only see the breaklines between sentences. The other tags need to stay how they are.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you just want to decode that tag, it sounds like all you really need is a bog-standard string replace:

```
var myString = "&lt;b&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;i&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;a&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt;&lt;br /&gt";
var outputString = myString.Replace("&lr;br /&gt;", "<br />");
```

Comment: I really need the Server.HtmlDecode usage to get breaklines between sentences, but still thanks.

Comment: There's no difference between using `HtmlDecode` and doing a straight string replace if you are just targeting a specific tag, so if this doesn't achieve what you want then you've missed crucial information out of your question.

Comment: For example: If I do: Server.HtmlDecode("&lr;br /&gt"), it will result in a breakline, and the replace function doesn't.

Comment: Yes, it will. The two things produce identical results. http://dotnetfiddle.net/O5vj4m - if it's not working, you're doing something wrong somewhere else.

Comment: Yes, you're right :) I forgot one ';' :-) Thanks for your help!